# Calling PHP function from Javascript then change form action

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to change my form action in my HTML then submit using javascript.

The conditions are in PHP .

I need help if anyone can assist me.

This is my PHP function :-

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $email=$_POST['email'];
   if(!empty($email)) {
       $chrono = 0;
    } else {
       $chrono = 1;
    }
}
?>
```

The motive of the PHP is to check null email entry.

Here's the javascript function :-

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function fireform(val){ 
    // missing codes
      document.forms["demoform"].action=val; 
      document.forms["demoform"].submit(); 
    } 
    // missing codes    
</script>
```

HTML :-

```
<form name="demoform" action="">        
<input type ="text" name="name" id="name">             
<input type="hidden" name="buttonpressed" id="buttonpressed"> 
<input type="button" value="submit B" onclick="fireform('b')">
```

I want to do it in a way , when the user entered an empty email , the PHP will read it as `chrono = 0`.
Then goes to javascript , if the chrono equal to 0 , the action will remain empty.

If the chrono = 1 , the javascript will change the action of the form and submit.

I need help thanks.

Comment: 1. What is wrong here? 2. `if $email =""` needs brackets.

Comment: @u_mulder, oh i didn't update the PHP , but the javascript function is the main part i need to focus. To change the document.form to the action when the chrono is equal to 0.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of checking it by php, can't you just check it all in js?

Comment: and while you add the brackets also change `$email =""` to `if(!empty($email))`

Comment: @AminJafari Js can edited by a user php can't. You can also turn off js and completely bypass it

Comment: @SuperDJ, changed . now left is the javascript section..i need help as my javascript is not that good.

Answer (score 1):

Your flow is unclear: it seems that you want to change the form action from PHP, but PHP is triggered after the form submission. So there's something weird in your flow. You also don't seem to have a field called **email** in your markup. Add it (or rename the field `name`):

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email">
```

Nonetheless, having an empty action means the form will be submitted to the page itself.

Probably what you need is a client side validation of the email field. In the `fireform()` JavaScript function, just add a check for email field:

```
function fireform(val){
    if (document.forms["demoform"].email.value.length > 0){
        document.forms["demoform"].action = val; 
        document.forms["demoform"].submit();
    }
}
```

This should be enough to get what you need.

Comment: But it's not possible to invoke the javascript function using php ??

Comment: not directly: PHP is a server side language, while JS works client side (well.. let's assume that for the moment). It would be possible to do a server side check AFTER you submit the form, but there is no reason to do that before. Why would you do that? JavaScript is not enough? Is it possible that you have an issue on how you designed your flow?

Comment: My flow is like this :-
1.User enter email in the form.
2.I plan to use isset submit, if email is valid chrono is 1.
3.Read back javascript, if chrono is 1.
4.Javascript will change action of the form and resubmit.

Comment: That's not a *real world* flow. Usually, form is checked/validated in JavaScript before submission, then submitted to its action (e.g. a PHP script) and then checked again. What you ask is possible theoretically (as almost everything is) but makes no real sense

Comment: It's like handling many action with just 1 button by using javascript.

Comment: *using javascript*, correct. So, what's the point of using PHP to change the action here?

Comment: Conditions and statement, 

i use php on the page cause i don't want the page to redirect.
Thus when issetsubmit is triggered it will check conditions then pass.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't really get what you mean, it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: That's not the usual flow. You can *generate* javascript with PHP, but not call javascript function directly from PHP. You usually have something like HTML+JS > PHP.

Comment: I'm interested to know javascript with PHP.
Is it using : header('Content-Type: application/x-javascript');?
Then normally put the javascript in the PHP?

Comment: No, it's not normal. It' a very intricated way to do things. What's the matter with PHP? Why can't you only use JavaScript for the form validation? Using PHP in this context doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I'm planning to implement to check email verification using SMTP.
If the email exists , it will proceed else shows a javascript error

Comment: I'm sorry, this will be my last comment, this discussion is not constructive anymore. If you need to show a javascript error, then you need to validate it in javascript. Why on Earth you want to use PHP for something that is supposed to be checked in JavaScript? For your needs (now it looks like you have a database or something), you will need AJAX. In `fireform` funcion, you need to add an AJAX call to a PHP script that checks on database the existence of that email, then, with a callback, it shows a possible javascript error. Now, I think this is something we can't write in a simple comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking the email field (for being empty) in javascript, and when you have set the proper action submit the form in javascript.

Check the field:

```
$('#<enter id of field>').val();
```

Update the action:

```
$('form').attr('action', 'Enter your updatet action here');
```

Submit the form:

http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: why adding jQuery for a simple input check?

Comment: The question contains the tag jQuery, so I am assuming jquery is already being used